# How to estimate the remaining time in a git push?

Tags: git, gitlab

```
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects:  92% (13/14), 770.27 MiB | 456.00 KiB/s
```

The total size of all the files is 2GB-3GB. There is one big file(2GB) and the size of the other files is around 500MB.

Because of the time, I stop the first push and then delete the largest file (about 2GB).

I have no idea how long time it will take......

Comment: You could probably estimate it by examining the files on disk and figuring out how big the compressed version of those files are, and then using that in conjunction with the speed. **But**, I can tell you that you **most likely** do **not** want to commit this big files to begin with. If you have 14 files, one of which is 2GB and the others are 500MB in total (or is that each?), it doesn't sound like you should be using version control at all, more like a backup service. Have you looked into git lfs (large file system)?

Comment: Also, how did you delete this big file? Did you just remove the file and commit the change? That doesn't get rid of the file, it's still present in history and thus still need to be pushed. To answer your question, nobody here can tell you how long this will take.